# How can I get ZSH shared history to work?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, history

I have `setopt share_history` and `set opt inc_append_history` set in my `~/.zshrc`. This is *almost* working.

In session 1, I execute a command, it's written to history.

In session 2, the command is not visible when I press the <kbd>UP</kbd> arrow, until I execute `history`. Once I execute `history` it appears.

How can I get history to show up immediately when I press the <kbd>UP</kbd> arrow?

Comment: Instead of `history`, is it also working when you only press the `ENTER` key and then `UP ARROW`?

Comment: Yes, if I please `ENTER` and then `UP` the history is correct. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the *Z shell* displays the prompt it is idle and IMHO does not do any background tasks. So, the history file `$HISTFILE` is re-read only when rendering a new prompt. That why it is sufficient, but also necessary that you press `ENTER` in a terminal to re-read your history.

If you you want to save this additional keystroke you can use the following *zle widget* in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
up-line-or-history-reread() {
        [[ -z $BUFFER ]] && fc -R $HISTFILE
        zle up-line-or-history
}
zle -N up-line-or-history-reread
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-history-reread
```

This new widget, which is bound to `UP ARROW`, checks if the current command line is empty and if so re-reads the history. After that it invokes the default widget (`up-line-or-history`).

This approach has at least these two flaws compared to the default behavior:

- If you're up in the history a few command, and delete the entire command line, the next press on `UP ARROW` starts again at the end of the command history.
- If you use some other history machanism, like history search, you still need to press the `ENTER` key before or you write a similar widget for these purposes, too.

Comment: Thanks, I was more confused thinking that it wasn't working. Now that I know how it works, it all makes sense. Thank you :)